# Concurrent Queue in Java that only retains the last item of each child thread

Tags: java, concurrency, queue, java.util.concurrent

I have 1 main thread which starts up `n` child threads. Each of these child threads continually produce an new event and add it to the shared queue. That event represents the latest state of a complex calculation on the child thread.

The main thread consumes that shared queue, but it's not interested in processing all events still on the queue: if a single child thread posted 3 events to the queue, the main thread is only interested in the last one. The older events of that child thread can be discarded (as soon as the child thread adds the newer event).

For example:

```
childThread A adds event A1
mainThread removes event A1

childThread B adds event B1
childThread B adds event B2 // => B1 should be discarded
childThread B adds event B3 // => B2 should be discarded
mainThread removes event B3

childThread A adds event A2
childThread A adds event A3 // => A2 should be discarded
childThread B adds event B4
mainThread removes event A3
mainThread removes event B4

childThread B adds event B5
childThread A adds event A4
childThread A adds event A5 // => A4 should be discarded
childThread B adds event B6 // => B5 should be discarded
childThread A adds event A6 // => A5 should be discarded
mainThread removes event B6 // do B6 first because B5 was before A4
mainThread removes event A6
```

Optional requirement: The main thread does want to round-robin as much as possible over the events of the child threads, but still block if none of the child threads are producing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use two DataStructures: 1 BlockingQueue for "triggers" and 1 Map for reference to the latest event.

EventSource will:

1. On new Event make an entry to the Map (updating an older one when key already exists) Key = "this" (EventSource) , Value = Latest Event
2. On new Event make an entry to the BlockingQueue with "this"(EventSource) but only if there is not already one in there.

The last part is quite optional. It just reduces unsuccessful lookups into the map. You could as well just add triggers on each new Event. Everytime a lookup is negative for a key in the map just ignore it.

The consumer will:

1. Wait on the blocking queue for not empty.
2. Remove top, use it as key into Event-Map ...
3. Key not found: continue with next queue item.
4. Key found: remove entry and process value (which is the event)
5. Loop to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular `BlockingQueue`, but the node object that is contained in the queue has a synchronized flag called `wasConsumed`. It starts off as `false` and the main consumer sets it to `true` whenever it starts working.

Each threads keeps the last item that it had enqueued. If the thread has an update and the last item wasn't consumed it updates the enqueued item using the same synchronization as before. Otherwise, it enqueues a new job.

```
class UpdateableNode<T>
{
  private boolean wasConsumed;
  private T task;

  // main consumer calls this BEFORE processing the task
  synchronized void startConsuming()
  {
    wasConsumed=true;
  }

  // producer tries to update the task if it wasn't consumed
  synchronized boolean tryUpdate(T newTask)
  {
    if (wasConsumed)
      return false;
    task = newTask;
    return true;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After understanding the previous concept, the same thing can be managed using `AtomicReference` instead of our crude `UpdatableNode`

Consumer code:

1. Pop an `AtomicReference<Task> ref` from the `BlockingQueue`
2. Get the Task by calling `Task t = ref.getAndSet(null)` this will clear the task from ref and return it in an atomic fashion (lockfree on most platforms).

Producer code:

1. Keep the last task `Task lastTask`
2. Keep the last ref `AtomicReference<Task> lastRef`
3. When a new task arrives try to update `lastRef.compareAndSet(lastTask, newTask)` it will only work if the old task is still in ref and wasn't consumed.
4. If it fails, create a new `AtomicReference<Task>`, enqueue it and save it in lastRef.
5. In both cases, save `newTask` in `lastTask`

Comment: Shouldn't `wasConsumed=true` and the removal of that node from the queue be in the same `synchronized` block (so the add can't intersect in a race condition)?

Comment: No. Even if it was removed from the queue, it can still be updated if the consumer did not start consuming it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `CorrurentMap` that accepts as a Key the Thread, and as a Value the Event. Since for Maps you can only have one Value for each Key, this is exactly what you are looking for. And since it is shared by many Threads, it is ideal to use a Concurrent version.

Check the documents on one of the `CorrurentMap` implementations, the `ConcurrentHashMap`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

EDIT:

After thinking for a bit, I came up with a possible solution. it is simple, but I hope it helps:

```java
public class EventHandler implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue<Thread> blockingQueue;
    private final ConcurrentMap<Thread, Event> eventMap;
    private final AtomicReference<Boolean> machineState;

    public EventHandler() {
        int threadNumber = 3;
        blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Thread>( threadNumber );
        eventMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Thread, Event>();
        machineState = new AtomicReference( Boolean.TRUE );
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while ( machineState.get() ) {
            Event toConsume = null;

            //We don't want Threads to medle in while we are removing it from the map AND the queue;
            synchronized ( this ) { 
                Thread eventParent = null;
                try {
                    eventParent = blockingQueue.take();
                }
                catch ( InterruptedException ex ) {
                    //Exception Handling;
                }

                toConsume = eventMap.remove( eventParent );
            }

            runEvent( toConsume );
        }
    }

    private void runEvent( Event toConsume ) {
        //Event Handling
    }

    //Notice that this method is syncronized
    public synchronized void addEvent( Event event ) {
        Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
        eventMap.put( thisThread, event );

        //Now checking and removing old unpoped Events, if any

        for ( Iterator<Thread> iterator = blockingQueue.iterator() ; iterator.hasNext() ; ) {
            Thread next = iterator.next();
            if( next == thisThread ) {
                iterator.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
        blockingQueue.offer( thisThread );
    }

    //Other methods...

}
```

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)

Comment: how do you consume this map?

Comment: What do you mean by consume? To clear the map? Just use `map.clear();`.

Comment: I mean how do you get elements from this map when there are elements available while not be busy waiting on it when there is none. Also check Fildor's answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a possible solution. It's a simple one, but it does the thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a queue of atomic references. The references hold the most recent item. When the consumer consumes an item, it will also clear the reference atomically via `getAndSet`. Hence, the producing thread, which retains the reference, can check whether the item has been consumed. If not, it will update the reference via `compareAndSet`, otherwise, it will enqueue the reference.

Like

```
ExecutorService es=Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
BlockingQueue<AtomicReference<String>> queue=new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(20);
es.execute(() -> { // consumer
    while(!Thread.interrupted()) try {
        String item=queue.take().getAndSet(null);
        System.out.println("consuming "+item);
        Thread.sleep(10);// simulate workload
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) { break; }
});
for(int i=0; i<20; i++) { // schedule multiple producers
    String name="T"+i;
    es.execute(() -> { // producer
        AtomicReference<String> lastItem=new AtomicReference<>();
        for(int item=0; item<100; item++) try {
            String current=name+" - item "+item;
            String last=lastItem.get();
            if(last==null || !lastItem.compareAndSet(last, current)) {
                lastItem.set(current);
                queue.put(lastItem);
            }
            Thread.sleep(5);// simulate workload
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex) { 
            System.err.println(name+" interrupted");
            break;
        }
    });
}
```

This has some degree of “fairness”, as after one atomic reference has been consumed, it will be put at the end of the queue. If you construct the queue with `fair` parameter set to `true`, it will indeed exhibit a round robin like behavior, once all threads have enqueued their reference the first time. If, however, a thread starts so slowly that it doesn’t manage to enqueue its first item before another one finished its last item, it will not be entirely fair, but I suppose, you don’t want to enforce “fairness” under such conditions anyway.